# maxima bug in distrib core library using cdf_binomial?

Tags: maxima, binomial-cdf

I am pretty new to maxima, which I installed a few days ago via `brew` on MacOS ARM.  ergo, I do not know whether I found a bug, or a feature, or I am doing something stupid altogether.  The following example shows the unexpected error I get:

```
$ maxima
Maxima 5.46.0 https://maxima.sourceforge.io
using Lisp SBCL 2.3.3
Distributed under the GNU Public License. See the file COPYING.
Dedicated to the memory of William Schelter.
The function bug_report() provides bug reporting information.
(%i1) load ("distrib"); 
(%o1) /opt/homebrew/Cellar/maxima/5.46.0_11/share/maxima/5.46.0/share/distrib/\
distrib.mac
(%i2) cdf_binomial(4,4,p);
(%o2)                                  1
(%i3) subst( [S=3], cdf_binomial(S,4,p)); 
                                     3    2
(%o3)                      (1 - p) (p  + p  + p + 1)
(%i4) subst( [S=4], cdf_binomial(S,4,p));

beta_incomplete: beta_incomplete(0,5,1-p) is undefined.
 -- an error. To debug this try: debugmode(true);
(%i5)
```

Am I doing something wrong here?  (PS: My real use will be integrating over p up to 1, which also triggers this problem.)  Are there standard workarounds?

Advice appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, the error you're seeing is actually a subtle consequence of the way unevaluated conditional expressions are handled. (An example of an unevaluated conditional is returned by `cdf_binomial(S, 4, p)`.) A simpler example of the bug (I'll create a bug report) is `'(if 0 > 0 then 0/0 else inf)` which bumps into a division by 0 error even though `0 > 0` is false. As a workaround, try `ev(myexpr, S = 4)` where `myexpr` is assigned the value returned by `cdf_binomial(S, 4, p)`. You mentioned integrals -- can you say more about the bigger picture you are working in?

Comment: dankeschoen.  please make this the answer, so I can checkmark it.  as noted: `load ("distrib")$ LOOPVAR: 8$ quad_qags(subst( [S=LOOPVAR], cdf_binomial(S/2,4,p)), p, 0, 1);` raised the error.  (my problem has more stuff than just the cdf, but it is one of the ingredients.)  fortunately, `lload ("distrib")$ LOOPVAR: 8$ quad_qags(  ev( cdf_binomial(S/2,4,p), S=LOOPVAR), p, 0, 1 );` works! (maybe `beta_incomplete` could be robustified against this buglet?)   would you be ok answering a question about differences in evaluation methods like subst, ev, [others?]?

Comment: Glad to hear it's working for you. I've created an answer below. Feel free to ask additional questions about any topics, I'll try to answer.

Comment: I looked into recognizing `beta_incomplete_regularized(0, n, z) = 1` and it looks like that enables `subst` and `quad_qags` to succeed. See the edit to my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're seeing is actually a subtle consequence of the way unevaluated conditional expressions are handled. (An example of an unevaluated conditional is returned by `cdf_binomial(S, 4, p)`.) A simpler example of the bug (I'll create a bug report) is `'(if 0 > 0 then 0/0 else inf)` which bumps into a division by 0 error even though `0 > 0` is false.

As a workaround, try `ev(myexpr, S = 4)` where `myexpr` is assigned the value returned by `cdf_binomial(S, 4, p)`.

This detour via `ev` is unnecessary if `S` has an assigned value -- in that case, `cdf_binomial` returns one case or another, and doesn't return an unevaluated conditional. The need for special handling comes into play when `cdf_binomial` was called with `S` not having an assigned value, so `cdf_binomial` didn't know which branch to take and therefore returned an unevaluated conditional.

EDIT: I also investigating equipping `beta_incomplete_regularized` with an additional identity for the first argument being zero. Looks like `beta_incomplete_regularized(0, n, z)` equals 1, at least when `n` is an integer. I'll look for a reference for that, but in the meantime one can tell Maxima to recognize that identity via `tellsimp`.

```
(%i2) matchdeclare (nn, integerp) $             
(%i3) matchdeclare (zz, all) $

(%i4) tellsimp (beta_incomplete_regularized (0, nn, zz), 1) $

(%i5) beta_incomplete_regularized (0, 5, z);
(%o5)                           1
(%i6) load (distrib);
(%o6) /usr/local/share/maxima/branch_5_46_base_1803_g61b2abdd9/s\
hare/distrib/distrib.mac
(%i7) cdf_binomial (S, 4, p);
(%o7) if S < 0 then 0 elseif S >= 4 then 1
 else beta_incomplete_regularized(4 - floor(S), floor(S) + 1, 
1 - p)
```

Now the substitution into the unevaluated conditional is okay because `beta_incomplete_regularized` doesn't complain.

```
(%i8) subst (S = 4, %);
(%o8)      if 4 < 0 then 0 elseif 4 >= 4 then 1 else 1
```

The literal inequalities `4 < 0` and `4 >= 4` require an explicit evaluation (a long story which I'll omit) to derive `false` and `true` from them.

```
(%i9) ''%;
(%o9)                           1
```

Now the call to `quad_qags` succeeds.

```
(%i10) quad_qags (subst (S = 4, cdf_binomial (S, 4, p)), p, 0, 1);
(%o10)         [1.0, 1.110223024625157e-14, 21, 0]
```